# Flexbox breakpoints not responding for two columns

Tags: html, css, responsive-design, flexbox

This is actually a Udacity assignment but you guys respond sooner. I'm starting to work on my understanding of flexbox and for the life of me can't figure out how to get the '.hero' and '.content' classes on the same line in two columns. For whatever reason it's just not responding even though I set up a media query with breakpoints and put an extra container around both both classes. Nothing I'm trying is working, the width for both elements stays at 100%. Can someone help me out? I'm so confused.

```css
body,
html {
    margin: 0;
    padding: 0;
    width: 100%;
    height: 100%;
}

body {
    font-family: Roboto;
    font-size: 12px;
    color: #424242;
}

h1,
h2,
h3,
h4,
h5 {
    margin: 0;
}

header,
nav,
footer,
section,
article,
div {
    box-sizing: border-box;
}

ul {
    list-style: none;
    padding: 0;
    margin: 0;
}

/*
 *
 * Common
 *
 */

.news__more {
    float: right;
    font-size: .8em;
    color: #333;
    text-decoration: none;
}

/*
 *
 * Header
 *
 */

.header {
    box-shadow: 0 2px 5px rgba(0, 0, 0, 0.26);
    min-height: 56px;
    transition: min-height 0.3s;
}

.header__inner {
    width: 100%;
    margin-left: auto;
    margin-right: auto;
}

.header__logo {
    height: 72px;
    margin-right: 1em;
    vertical-align: top;
    margin-top: 12px;
}

.header__title {
    font-weight: 300;
    font-size: 4em;
    margin: 0.5em 0.25em;
    display: inline-block;
    color: #212121;
}

/*
 *
 * Top Level Navigation
 *
 */

.nav {
    width: 100%;
    margin-left: auto;
    margin-right: auto;
}

.nav__list {
    width: 100%;
    padding: 0;
    margin: 0;
}

.nav__item {
    box-sizing: border-box;
    display: inline-block;
    width: 24%;
    text-align: center;
    line-height: 24px;
    padding: 24px;
    text-transform: uppercase;
}

.nav a {
    text-decoration: none;
    color: #616161;
    padding: 1.5em;
}

.nav a:hover {
    text-decoration: underline;
    color: #212121;
}

/*
 *
 * Main
 *
 */

main {
    box-shadow: 0 2px 5px rgba(0, 0, 0, 0.26);
    width: 100%;
    margin-left: auto;
    margin-right: auto;
}

/*
 *
 * Content
 *
 */

/*
 *
 * Hero
 *
 */

.hero {
    width: 100%;
    position: relative;
    background-image: url("./images/dog.jpg");
    background-size: cover;
    height: 300px;
}

.hero article {
    box-sizing: border-box;
    background-color: #000;
    background-color: rgba(0, 0, 0, 0.7);
    position: absolute;
    bottom: 0;
    height: 40%;
    width: 100%;
    color: #fff;
    padding: 1em;
}

/*
 *
 * Top News
 *
 */

.top-news {
    height: 300px;
    border-bottom: 1px solid #E0E0E0;
    padding: 1em;
}

.news__title {
    font-weight: 300;
    border-bottom: 1px solid #E0E0E0;
    line-height: 24px;
    font-size: 16px;
}

.top-news__item {
    border-bottom: 1px solid #E0E0E0;
    padding: 1em 0;
    line-height: 19.2px;
}

.top-news__item:before {
    content: "» ";
}

.top-news__item:last-child {
    border-bottom: none;
}

.top-news__item a {
    text-decoration: none;
    color: #666;
}

.top-news__item a:hover,
.top-news__item a:active {
    text-decoration: underline;
}

/*
 *
 * Sport Scores
 *
 */

.scores {
    padding-top: 1em;
}

.scores__table {
    width: 100%;
    border-collapse: collapse;
}

.scores__table th,
.scores__table td {
    padding: 1em;
}

.scores__table th {
    color: #fff;
    font-weight: 300;
    background-color: #78909C;
}

.scores__table tr:nth-child(odd) td {
    background-color: #fff;
}

.scores__table tr:nth-child(even) td {
    background-color: #eceff1;
}

.scores__table td.winner {
    font-weight: bold;
}

.scores__table td:nth-child(3) {
    text-align: right;
}

.scores__table td:nth-child(2),
.scores__table td:nth-child(5) {
    text-align: center;
}

/*
 *
 * Weather
 *
 */

.weather {
    padding: 1em;
}

.weather__location {
    display: block;
    font-weight: 300;
    font-size: 1.5em;
}

.weather__desc {
    display: block;
    font-size: 1.2em;
}

.weather__today {
    width: 60%;
    vertical-align: middle;
}

.weather__today__image {
    vertical-align: middle
}

.weather__today__temp {
    font-size: 3em;
}

.weather__today__deg {
    font-size: 2em;
    display: inline;
}

.weather__next__item {
    display: inline-block;
    width: 20%;
    text-align: center;
}

.weather__next__item span {
    display: block;
}

.weather__next__image {
    width: 100%;
}

/*
 *
 * Recent News
 *
 */

.recent-news {
    clear: both;
    padding: 1em;
}

.snippet {
    clear: both;
    margin: 24px 0;
}

.snippet__thumbnail {
    width: 100px;
    float: left;
    margin-right: 1em;
}

.snippet__title {
    font-weight: 500;
}

.snippet__title a {
    text-decoration: none;
    color: #666;
}

.snippet__title a:hover,
.snippet__title a:active {
    text-decoration: underline;
}

/*
 *
 * Footer
 *
 */

footer {
    border-top: 1px solid #E0E0E0;
    padding: 1em;
    width: 100%;
}

footer li {
    display: inline-block;
    margin: 0 1em;
}

footer a {
    text-decoration: none;
    color: #333;
    padding: 1.5em;
}

/*
*
* media queries
 *
 */

@media screen and (min-width: 660 px) {
    .container-main {
        display: flex;
        align-content: center;
    }
    .news {
        width: 200px;
        float: right
    }
    .hero {
        width: 200px;
    }
}
```

```html
<!doctype html>
<html lang="en">

<head>
      <meta charset="utf-8">
      <meta name="viewport" content="width=device-width,initial-scale=1">
      <meta http-equiv="X-UA-Compatible" content="IE=edge">
      <title>Brighton Times</title>
      <link href="https://fonts.googleapis.com/css?family=Roboto:300,400,500" rel="stylesheet" type="text/css">
      <link rel="stylesheet" type="text/css" href="main.css">
</head>

<body>

      <header class="header">
            <div class="header__inner">
                  <img class="header__logo" src="images/city.png" alt="iconic view of a cityscape">
                  <h1 class="header__title">
                        The Brighton Times
                  </h1>
            </div>
      </header>

      <nav id="drawer" class="nav">
            <ul class="nav__list">
                  <li class="nav__item">
                        <a href="#">News</a>
                  </li>
                  <li class="nav__item">
                        <a href="#">Events</a>
                  </li>
                  <li class="nav__item">
                        <a href="#">Culture</a>
                  </li>
                  <li class="nav__item">
                        <a href="#">Blog</a>
                  </li>
            </ul>
      </nav>

      <main>
            <section class="content">
                  <section class="container-main">
                        <section class="hero">
                              <article class="description">
                                    <h2>Absolutely astonishing breaking news!</h2>
                                    <p>Organic raw denim Vice keffiyeh lomo Kickstarter art lomo Kickstarter art four loko.
                                          Organic raw denim Vice keffiyeh lomo Kickstarter art lomo Kickstarter art four
                                          loko.</p>
                              </article>
                        </section>

                        <section class="news top-news">
                              <h2 class="news__title">Top news
                                    <a href="#" class="news__more">+ more</a>
                              </h2>
                              <ul>
                                    <li class="top-news__item">
                                          <a href="#">Gastropub distillery Marfa farm-to-table, Etsy Truffaut fingerstache.</a>
                                    </li>
                                    <li class="top-news__item">
                                          <a href="#">Squid lomo Kickstarter art lomo Kickstarter art party cronut scenester.</a>
                                    </li>
                                    <li class="top-news__item">
                                          <a href="#">Organic raw denim lomo Kickstarter art Vice keffiyeh four loko.</a>
                                    </li>
                                    <li class="top-news__item">
                                          <a href="#">Organic raw denim Vice keffiyeh lomo Kickstarter art lomo Kickstarter art four
                                                loko.</a>
                                    </li>
                              </ul>
                        </section>
                  </section>
            </section>

            <section class="scores">
                  <table class="scores__table">
                        <thead>
                              <tr>
                                    <th>date</th>
                                    <th>team</th>
                                    <th colspan="2">score</th>
                                    <th>team</th>
                              </tr>
                        </thead>
                        <tbody>
                              <tr>
                                    <td>Friday</td>
                                    <td>Bears</td>
                                    <td>95</td>
                                    <td class="winner">109</td>
                                    <td class="winner">Cubs</td>
                              </tr>
                              <tr>
                                    <td>Friday</td>
                                    <td class="winner">Otters</td>
                                    <td class="winner">3</td>
                                    <td>1</td>
                                    <td>Cubs</td>
                              </tr>
                              <tr>
                                    <td>Saturday</td>
                                    <td class="winner">Wolves</td>
                                    <td class="winner">7</td>
                                    <td>0</td>
                                    <td>Panthers</td>
                              </tr>
                              <tr>
                                    <td>Sunday</td>
                                    <td>Hawks</td>
                                    <td>11</td>
                                    <td class="winner">12</td>
                                    <td class="winner">Capons</td>
                              </tr>
                              <tr>
                                    <td>Sunday</td>
                                    <td class="winner">Stags</td>
                                    <td class="winner">6</td>
                                    <td>2</td>
                                    <td>Foxes</td>
                              </tr>

                        </tbody>
                  </table>
            </section>

            <section class="weather">
                  <span class="weather__location">Brighton, UK</span>
                  <span class="weather__desc">Sunny</span>
                  <span class="weather__today">
                        <img class="weather__today__image" src="images/weather.png" alt="icon of a partially sunny day">
                        <span class="weather__today__temp">13</span>
                        <span class="weather__today__deg">&deg;C</span>
                  </span>
                  <ul class="weather__next">
                        <li class="weather__next__item">
                              <span>Mon</span>
                              <img class="weather__next__image" src="images/sunny.png" alt="icon of a sunny day">
                              <span>13 &deg;C</span>
                        </li>
                        <li class="weather__next__item">
                              <span>Tues</span>
                              <img class="weather__next__image" src="images/cloudy.png" alt="icon of a cloudy day">
                              <span>13 &deg;C</span>
                        </li>
                        <li class="weather__next__item">
                              <span>Wed</span>
                              <img class="weather__next__image" src="images/cloudy.png" alt="icon of a cloudy day">
                              <span>13 &deg;C</span>
                        </li>
                        <li class="weather__next__item">
                              <span>Thu</span>
                              <img class="weather__next__image" src="images/rain.png" alt="icon of a rainy day">
                              <span>13 &deg;C</span>
                        </li>
                        <li class="weather__next__item">
                              <span>Fri</span>
                              <img class="weather__next__image" src="images/sunny.png" alt="icon of a sunny day">
                              <span>13 &deg;C</span>
                        </li>
                  </ul>
            </section>

            <section class="news recent-news">
                  <h2 class="news__title">Latest news
                        <a href="#" class="news__more">+ more</a>
                  </h2>
                  <ul>
                        <li class="snippet">
                              <img class="snippet__thumbnail" src="images/dog.jpg" alt="picture of a girl with a large, stuffed dog toy">
                              <h3 class="snippet__title">
                                    <a href="#">Gastropub distillery Marfa farm-to-table</a>
                              </h3>
                              <p>Gastropub distillery Marfa farm-to-table, Etsy Truffaut fingerstache. Squid lomo Kickstarter
                                    art party cronut scenester. Organic raw denim Vice keffiyeh four loko. Squid lomo Kickstarter
                                    art party cronut scenester. Organic raw denim Vice keffiyeh four loko.Vice keffiyeh four
                                    loko. Squid lomo Kickstarter art party cronut scenester. Organic raw denim Vice keffiyeh
                                    four loko.Vice keffiyeh four loko. Squid lomo Kickstarter art party cronut scenester.
                                    Organic raw denim Vice keffiyeh four loko.
                              </p>
                        </li>
                        <li class="snippet">
                              <img class="snippet__thumbnail" src="images/dog.jpg" alt="picture of a girl with a large, stuffed dog toy">
                              <h3 class="snippet__title">
                                    <a href="#">Organic raw keffiyeh four loko.</a>
                              </h3>
                              <p>Vice keffiyeh four loko. Squid lomo Kickstarter art party cronut scenester. Organic raw denim
                                    Vice keffiyeh four loko.Vice keffiyeh four loko. Squid lomo Kickstarter art party cronut
                                    scenester. Organic raw denim Vice loko.
                              </p>
                        </li>
                        <li class="snippet">
                              <img class="snippet__thumbnail" src="images/dog.jpg" alt="picture of a girl with a large, stuffed dog toy">
                              <h3 class="snippet__title">
                                    <a href="#">Kickstarter art party cronut scenester.</a>
                              </h3>
                              <p>Gastropub distillery Marfa farm-to-table, Etsy Truffaut fingerstache. Squid lomo Kickstarter
                                    art party cronut scenester. Organic raw denim Vice keffiyeh four loko. Squid lomo Kickstarter
                                    art party cronut scenester. Organic raw denim Vice keffiyeh four loko.Vice keffiyeh four
                                    loko.
                              </p>
                        </li>
                        <li class="snippet">
                              <img class="snippet__thumbnail" src="images/dog.jpg" alt="picture of a girl with a large, stuffed dog toy">
                              <h3 class="snippet__title">
                                    <a href="#">Squid lomo Kickstarter art party cronut </a>
                              </h3>
                              <p>Gastropub distillery Marfa farm-to-table, Etsy Truffaut fingerstache. Squid lomo Kickstarter
                                    art party cronut scenester. Organic raw denim Vice keffiyeh four loko. Squid lomo Kickstarter
                                    art party cronut scenester. Organic raw denim Vice keffiyeh four loko.Vice keffiyeh four
                                    loko.
                              </p>
                        </li>
                  </ul>
            </section>
            </section>
            <footer>
                  <ul>
                        <li>
                              <a href="#">Contact us</a>
                        </li>
                        <li>
                              <a href="#">Follow us on Twitter</a>
                        </li>
                        <li>
                              <a href="#">RSS</a>
                        </li>
                  </ul>
            </footer>
      </main>
</body>

</html>
```

Comment: I made your code into snippet, also my question here is - .hero is a child of .content class and what are you trying to achieve?

Comment: Thanks for responding, I appreciate you adjusting my code. I'm trying to make it so that the news and hero sections of code are side by side.

Comment: You forgot to add flex-container class and connecting style, check my answer, hope that is what you are looking for.

Answer (score 1):

You missed to add flex-container. Also adjust your height, position for hero class as required.
Hope this helps!!

```css
body,
html {
  margin: 0;
  padding: 0;
  width: 100%;
  height: 100%;
}

body {
  font-family: Roboto;
  font-size: 12px;
  color: #424242;
}

h1,
h2,
h3,
h4,
h5 {
  margin: 0;
}

header,
nav,
footer,
section,
article,
div {
  box-sizing: border-box;
}

ul {
  list-style: none;
  padding: 0;
  margin: 0;
}


/*
 *
 * Common
 *
 */

.news__more {
  float: right;
  font-size: .8em;
  color: #333;
  text-decoration: none;
}


/*
 *
 * Header
 *
 */

.header {
  box-shadow: 0 2px 5px rgba(0, 0, 0, 0.26);
  min-height: 56px;
  transition: min-height 0.3s;
}

.header__inner {
  width: 100%;
  margin-left: auto;
  margin-right: auto;
}

.header__logo {
  height: 72px;
  margin-right: 1em;
  vertical-align: top;
  margin-top: 12px;
}

.header__title {
  font-weight: 300;
  font-size: 4em;
  margin: 0.5em 0.25em;
  display: inline-block;
  color: #212121;
}


/*
 *
 * Top Level Navigation
 *
 */

.nav {
  width: 100%;
  margin-left: auto;
  margin-right: auto;
}

.nav__list {
  width: 100%;
  padding: 0;
  margin: 0;
}

.nav__item {
  box-sizing: border-box;
  display: inline-block;
  width: 24%;
  text-align: center;
  line-height: 24px;
  padding: 24px;
  text-transform: uppercase;
}

.nav a {
  text-decoration: none;
  color: #616161;
  padding: 1.5em;
}

.nav a:hover {
  text-decoration: underline;
  color: #212121;
}


/*
 *
 * Main
 *
 */

main {
  box-shadow: 0 2px 5px rgba(0, 0, 0, 0.26);
  width: 100%;
  margin-left: auto;
  margin-right: auto;
}


/*
 *
 * Content
 *
 */


/*
 *
 * Hero
 *
 */

.hero {
  width: 100%;
  position: relative;
  background-image: url("./images/dog.jpg");
  background-size: cover;
  height: 300px;
}

.hero article {
  box-sizing: border-box;
  background-color: #000;
  background-color: rgba(0, 0, 0, 0.7);
  position: absolute;
  bottom: 0;
  height: 40%;
  width: 100%;
  color: #fff;
  padding: 1em;
}


/*
 *
 * Top News
 *
 */

.top-news {
  height: 300px;
  border-bottom: 1px solid #E0E0E0;
  padding: 1em;
}

.news__title {
  font-weight: 300;
  border-bottom: 1px solid #E0E0E0;
  line-height: 24px;
  font-size: 16px;
}

.top-news__item {
  border-bottom: 1px solid #E0E0E0;
  padding: 1em 0;
  line-height: 19.2px;
}

.top-news__item:before {
  content: "» ";
}

.top-news__item:last-child {
  border-bottom: none;
}

.top-news__item a {
  text-decoration: none;
  color: #666;
}

.top-news__item a:hover,
.top-news__item a:active {
  text-decoration: underline;
}


/*
 *
 * Sport Scores
 *
 */

.scores {
  padding-top: 1em;
}

.scores__table {
  width: 100%;
  border-collapse: collapse;
}

.scores__table th,
.scores__table td {
  padding: 1em;
}

.scores__table th {
  color: #fff;
  font-weight: 300;
  background-color: #78909C;
}

.scores__table tr:nth-child(odd) td {
  background-color: #fff;
}

.scores__table tr:nth-child(even) td {
  background-color: #eceff1;
}

.scores__table td.winner {
  font-weight: bold;
}

.scores__table td:nth-child(3) {
  text-align: right;
}

.scores__table td:nth-child(2),
.scores__table td:nth-child(5) {
  text-align: center;
}


/*
 *
 * Weather
 *
 */

.weather {
  padding: 1em;
}

.weather__location {
  display: block;
  font-weight: 300;
  font-size: 1.5em;
}

.weather__desc {
  display: block;
  font-size: 1.2em;
}

.weather__today {
  width: 60%;
  vertical-align: middle;
}

.weather__today__image {
  vertical-align: middle
}

.weather__today__temp {
  font-size: 3em;
}

.weather__today__deg {
  font-size: 2em;
  display: inline;
}

.weather__next__item {
  display: inline-block;
  width: 20%;
  text-align: center;
}

.weather__next__item span {
  display: block;
}

.weather__next__image {
  width: 100%;
}


/*
 *
 * Recent News
 *
 */

.recent-news {
  clear: both;
  padding: 1em;
}

.snippet {
  clear: both;
  margin: 24px 0;
}

.snippet__thumbnail {
  width: 100px;
  float: left;
  margin-right: 1em;
}

.snippet__title {
  font-weight: 500;
}

.snippet__title a {
  text-decoration: none;
  color: #666;
}

.snippet__title a:hover,
.snippet__title a:active {
  text-decoration: underline;
}


/*
 *
 * Footer
 *
 */

footer {
  border-top: 1px solid #E0E0E0;
  padding: 1em;
  width: 100%;
}

footer li {
  display: inline-block;
  margin: 0 1em;
}

footer a {
  text-decoration: none;
  color: #333;
  padding: 1.5em;
}


/*
*
* media queries
 *
 */

@media screen and (min-width: 660 px) {
  .container-main {
    display: flex;
    align-content: center;
  }
  .news {
    width: 200px;
    float: right
  }
  .hero {
    width: 200px;
  }
}

.flex-container {
  display: flex;
}
```

```html
<!doctype html>
<html lang="en">

<head>
  <meta charset="utf-8">
  <meta name="viewport" content="width=device-width,initial-scale=1">
  <meta http-equiv="X-UA-Compatible" content="IE=edge">
  <title>Brighton Times</title>
  <link href="https://fonts.googleapis.com/css?family=Roboto:300,400,500" rel="stylesheet" type="text/css">
  <link rel="stylesheet" type="text/css" href="main.css">
</head>

<body>

  <header class="header">
    <div class="header__inner">
      <img class="header__logo" src="images/city.png" alt="iconic view of a cityscape">
      <h1 class="header__title">
        The Brighton Times
      </h1>
    </div>
  </header>

  <nav id="drawer" class="nav">
    <ul class="nav__list">
      <li class="nav__item">
        <a href="#">News</a>
      </li>
      <li class="nav__item">
        <a href="#">Events</a>
      </li>
      <li class="nav__item">
        <a href="#">Culture</a>
      </li>
      <li class="nav__item">
        <a href="#">Blog</a>
      </li>
    </ul>
  </nav>

  <main>
    <section class="content">
      <section class="container-main flex-container">
        <section class="hero">
          <article class="description">
            <h2>Absolutely astonishing breaking news!</h2>
            <p>Organic raw denim Vice keffiyeh lomo Kickstarter art lomo Kickstarter art four loko. Organic raw denim Vice keffiyeh lomo Kickstarter art lomo Kickstarter art four loko.
            </p>
          </article>
        </section>

        <section class="news top-news">
          <h2 class="news__title">Top news
            <a href="#" class="news__more">+ more</a>
          </h2>
          <ul>
            <li class="top-news__item">
              <a href="#">Gastropub distillery Marfa farm-to-table, Etsy Truffaut fingerstache.</a>
            </li>
            <li class="top-news__item">
              <a href="#">Squid lomo Kickstarter art lomo Kickstarter art party cronut scenester.</a>
            </li>
            <li class="top-news__item">
              <a href="#">Organic raw denim lomo Kickstarter art Vice keffiyeh four loko.</a>
            </li>
            <li class="top-news__item">
              <a href="#">Organic raw denim Vice keffiyeh lomo Kickstarter art lomo Kickstarter art four
                                                loko.</a>
            </li>
          </ul>
        </section>
      </section>
    </section>

    <section class="scores">
      <table class="scores__table">
        <thead>
          <tr>
            <th>date</th>
            <th>team</th>
            <th colspan="2">score</th>
            <th>team</th>
          </tr>
        </thead>
        <tbody>
          <tr>
            <td>Friday</td>
            <td>Bears</td>
            <td>95</td>
            <td class="winner">109</td>
            <td class="winner">Cubs</td>
          </tr>
          <tr>
            <td>Friday</td>
            <td class="winner">Otters</td>
            <td class="winner">3</td>
            <td>1</td>
            <td>Cubs</td>
          </tr>
          <tr>
            <td>Saturday</td>
            <td class="winner">Wolves</td>
            <td class="winner">7</td>
            <td>0</td>
            <td>Panthers</td>
          </tr>
          <tr>
            <td>Sunday</td>
            <td>Hawks</td>
            <td>11</td>
            <td class="winner">12</td>
            <td class="winner">Capons</td>
          </tr>
          <tr>
            <td>Sunday</td>
            <td class="winner">Stags</td>
            <td class="winner">6</td>
            <td>2</td>
            <td>Foxes</td>
          </tr>

        </tbody>
      </table>
    </section>

    <section class="weather">
      <span class="weather__location">Brighton, UK</span>
      <span class="weather__desc">Sunny</span>
      <span class="weather__today">
                        <img class="weather__today__image" src="images/weather.png" alt="icon of a partially sunny day">
                        <span class="weather__today__temp">13</span>
      <span class="weather__today__deg">&deg;C</span>
      </span>
      <ul class="weather__next">
        <li class="weather__next__item">
          <span>Mon</span>
          <img class="weather__next__image" src="images/sunny.png" alt="icon of a sunny day">
          <span>13 &deg;C</span>
        </li>
        <li class="weather__next__item">
          <span>Tues</span>
          <img class="weather__next__image" src="images/cloudy.png" alt="icon of a cloudy day">
          <span>13 &deg;C</span>
        </li>
        <li class="weather__next__item">
          <span>Wed</span>
          <img class="weather__next__image" src="images/cloudy.png" alt="icon of a cloudy day">
          <span>13 &deg;C</span>
        </li>
        <li class="weather__next__item">
          <span>Thu</span>
          <img class="weather__next__image" src="images/rain.png" alt="icon of a rainy day">
          <span>13 &deg;C</span>
        </li>
        <li class="weather__next__item">
          <span>Fri</span>
          <img class="weather__next__image" src="images/sunny.png" alt="icon of a sunny day">
          <span>13 &deg;C</span>
        </li>
      </ul>
    </section>

    <section class="news recent-news">
      <h2 class="news__title">Latest news
        <a href="#" class="news__more">+ more</a>
      </h2>
      <ul>
        <li class="snippet">
          <img class="snippet__thumbnail" src="images/dog.jpg" alt="picture of a girl with a large, stuffed dog toy">
          <h3 class="snippet__title">
            <a href="#">Gastropub distillery Marfa farm-to-table</a>
          </h3>
          <p>Gastropub distillery Marfa farm-to-table, Etsy Truffaut fingerstache. Squid lomo Kickstarter art party cronut scenester. Organic raw denim Vice keffiyeh four loko. Squid lomo Kickstarter art party cronut scenester. Organic raw denim Vice keffiyeh
            four loko.Vice keffiyeh four loko. Squid lomo Kickstarter art party cronut scenester. Organic raw denim Vice keffiyeh four loko.Vice keffiyeh four loko. Squid lomo Kickstarter art party cronut scenester. Organic raw denim Vice keffiyeh four
            loko.
          </p>
        </li>
        <li class="snippet">
          <img class="snippet__thumbnail" src="images/dog.jpg" alt="picture of a girl with a large, stuffed dog toy">
          <h3 class="snippet__title">
            <a href="#">Organic raw keffiyeh four loko.</a>
          </h3>
          <p>Vice keffiyeh four loko. Squid lomo Kickstarter art party cronut scenester. Organic raw denim Vice keffiyeh four loko.Vice keffiyeh four loko. Squid lomo Kickstarter art party cronut scenester. Organic raw denim Vice loko.
          </p>
        </li>
        <li class="snippet">
          <img class="snippet__thumbnail" src="images/dog.jpg" alt="picture of a girl with a large, stuffed dog toy">
          <h3 class="snippet__title">
            <a href="#">Kickstarter art party cronut scenester.</a>
          </h3>
          <p>Gastropub distillery Marfa farm-to-table, Etsy Truffaut fingerstache. Squid lomo Kickstarter art party cronut scenester. Organic raw denim Vice keffiyeh four loko. Squid lomo Kickstarter art party cronut scenester. Organic raw denim Vice keffiyeh
            four loko.Vice keffiyeh four loko.
          </p>
        </li>
        <li class="snippet">
          <img class="snippet__thumbnail" src="images/dog.jpg" alt="picture of a girl with a large, stuffed dog toy">
          <h3 class="snippet__title">
            <a href="#">Squid lomo Kickstarter art party cronut </a>
          </h3>
          <p>Gastropub distillery Marfa farm-to-table, Etsy Truffaut fingerstache. Squid lomo Kickstarter art party cronut scenester. Organic raw denim Vice keffiyeh four loko. Squid lomo Kickstarter art party cronut scenester. Organic raw denim Vice keffiyeh
            four loko.Vice keffiyeh four loko.
          </p>
        </li>
      </ul>
    </section>
    </section>
    <footer>
      <ul>
        <li>
          <a href="#">Contact us</a>
        </li>
        <li>
          <a href="#">Follow us on Twitter</a>
        </li>
        <li>
          <a href="#">RSS</a>
        </li>
      </ul>
    </footer>
  </main>
</body>

</html>
```

Comment: sorry, I actually forgot to add that I need it to be one column on mobile devices, not two, hence the breakpoint at around 600px. it's actually good on mobile devices. atm.